# Using timestamp to show active users?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, timestamp

I am working on a quite simple custom made content management system (CMS). There is a database table containing usernames, passwords, emailaddresses and a date/time field showing when the user logged in for the last time (I used "NOW()" in the query when updating).

When an user successfully logs in, the script will update a table in the database and sets the new time (using NOW()).

Now I would like to show which users are currently logged in, in the past 5 or 10 minutes. I have no idea how to accomplish this, therefore I am calling for your help. On the internet I read I need to do this with a timestamp, but I have no idea how this works.

1. I need to know how to set a specific timestamp.
2. I need to know how I can check in PHP if the user has been logged in in the past 5 or 10 minutes so I  can display their names somewhere.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1.**
Why do you need to set a custom timestamp? Using NOW() is all you need.

**2.**  This query will find all users where the column `latest_login` is in the past 10 minutes:

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE latest_login >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)`

Comment: Thank you very much! Works great. Did not know it was possible this way.

Answer (score 0):

ok this is quite simple

1ts - convert your date into timestamp using function mktime (check google , lets say $date)

2nd - use function time() to get current timestamp (let say $now)

3rd if (   ($now - $date) > ( 5 * 60 /* 5 minute */  ) ) { return "not login" }
    else return "login"

timestamp counts seconds so 5*60  is 5 minutes